# Constructor of a function declaration

Tags: javascript

Why does the following hold:

```js
let F = function () {};
let f = new F();
console.log(f.__proto__.constructor === F, f.constructor === F);
// true
```

But the following does not:

```js
let F = function () {};
console.log(F.prototype.constructor === F, F.constructor === F);
// true false
```

What then would be the constructor of a function declaration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.constructor` property is an object is what you can call `new` on to create another such object.

That is, `someF.constructor` points to F, and you can use `new F()` to create `someOtherF`.

So, if F itself is what you want to make a similar type of object - what can you call to construct a function? `Function`.

```js
let F = function () {};
console.log(F.constructor === Function);
```

In other words - you could use `new Function` to create something similar to F - a function that can create instances when `new` is called on it.

(That said, this would be extremely unusual - 99% of the time, functions should not be dynamic - there's no good reason to use `new Function`)

Answer (score 0):

The constructor of a function is `Function`.

```js
let F = function () {};
console.log(F.__proto__.constructor === Function, F.constructor === Function);
// true false
```